# Chrome prevents angular setting dynamic offsets in svg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, svg

Premise: This code (although it may be considered a hack) has been working for about 2 years, but all of a sudden this has stopped working in google chrome (the rendering of the gradient colors in svgs) and I don't know when exactly that has stopped, but still works in Safari! (see the 2 attached screenshots at the bottom).

I have an ng-repeat in which I render items with timeseries data and a different svg icon per item that I render dynamically via ng-include based on the item property that coincides with the name of the icon like "icon.type.svg".

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="pull-right">
         <ng-include src="'img/icons/items/'+ item.type + '.svg'"></ng-include>
         <h4><a>{{item.name}}</a></h4>
         .....
    </div>
</div>
```

All the svg follow the same strategy and a sample code can be seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 40.6 60.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 40.6 60.2;" xml:space="preserve"  ng-attr-height="{{myIcon.height || '60px'}}">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
            <stop ng-attr-offset="{{getOffset(item.level)}}" stop-color="#34495e">
            </stop>
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{itemFillColor}}">
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
<path class="st0" d="M40.6,0H0v39v0.6c0,1.2-0.1,13.3,8.1,18.3c4,2.4,8.7,2.3,12.5,2.3c3.5,0,7.4-0.1,10.9-2
    c8.5-4.6,9.1-17.1,9.1-18.5v-0.6V0z"/>
<path class="st1" d="M5.4,53.4"/>
<path d="M39,1.7H1.5v36.8v0.6c0,1.1-0.1,12.6,7.5,17.3c3.7,2.3,8,2.2,11.5,2.2c3.2,0,6.8-0.1,10.1-1.9c7.8-4.3,8.4-16.1,8.4-17.5
    v-0.6V1.7z" fill="url(#grad)"/>
</svg>
```

Then in my controller I have a simple method (getOffset) as follows:

```
$scope.getOffset = function(level) {
    if (!level) return '100%';
    return (100 - level) + '%';
};
```

The way the icon work is kind of backward. They are 100% green (variable itemFillColor), and then the navy blue color, which is the actual body of the item, is then lowered from the top down to render the actual level.

Chrome Rendering
[image: Chrome rendering]

Safari Rendering
[image: Safari rendering]

With Chrome it seems like that whatever "level" the first container has (in this case is actually 0 (null)), is applied to all subsequent items in the ng-repeat.

Can someone advise me on how to solve this or know why this started to happen all of a sudden?

Is there a better way otherwise to do this or go around the issue?

Would love to hear why this happened.

Edit: To "prove" that my hunch is that is nothing wrong with the svg per se, I use the same svg and do the exact same approach in a page with a single item selected (no ng-repeat, but a single ng-include) and the result is correct:

Single Page view
[image: Single Page view]

Comment: The SVG spec says: Each gradient offset value is required to be equal to or greater than the previous gradient stop's offset value. Are you spec compliant?

Comment: Is that in sequential order from top to bottom? in my code "<linearGradient id="grad" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
            <stop ng-attr-offset="{{getLevel(container.level)}}" stop-color="#34495e">
            </stop>
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="{{containerFillColor}}">
            </stop>
        </linearGradient>" The firs gradient will always be bigger than the 2nd (which is always 0) and the other gradient (the blue color), will always lower from top to bottom in the icon. I just tried to invert them and it does not have any effect :(

Comment: See edited question (@bottom)

Comment: When you use ng-repeat, do you end up with more than one element having the same id e.g. more than one id="grad" element. That's invalid too.

Comment: Hi Robert, that seems to have been the issue! :/ However to fix it i need to pass dynamically a variable into the svg file i load. Any idea how to navigate around this?

Comment: Isn't that what you're already doing with itemFillColor and item.level?

Comment: Got it. In the svg file I have a ng-init="dynamicFillVariable = "getFillRandomId()" and getFillRandomId() just return Date.now(). Then in then in my linearGradient i do <linearGradient ng-attr-id="{{dynamicFillVariable}}">...</linearGradient> and in the path I have to fill i do: <path ... fill="url(#{{dynamicFillVariable}})" > ..